# Can I use System.Drawing.Color in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using C# and javascript binding (via chromium control).

I am passing `System.Drawing.Color` from C# to javascript.

In javascript: Color[A=255, R=118, G=146, B=60]

Is there any way to get Color from javascript without performing any conversion when passing in C#?

```
// not working...
// color : System.Drawing.Color (C# binding)
function(color) 
{
    String(color).replace("Color", "");
    String(color).replace("[", "");
    String(color).replace("]", "");
    String(color).replace("A=", "");
    String(color).replace("R=", "");
    String(color).replace("G=", "");
    String(color).replace("B=", "");
    String(color).replace("A=", "");
    const colorStr = String(color).split(',');
}
```

Comment: "C# binding" - how does this work?

Comment: Are you talking about Java? Not JavaScript? May you give more context?

Comment: I am using JavaScript.
C#'s chromium control contains html(javascript) and binds it.

Comment: Can you provide more code (the javascript binding code)? How are you passing colors from C# to javascript and vice versa? A conversion will most likely be needed on C# side but depending on the way you're passing the colors it could be very simple to do

Comment: .NET doesn't have a Chromium control built-in....

Comment: @John there isn't one built in but you can use third-party ones like [**CefSharp**](https://cefsharp.github.io/) (most likely the one used here). So the question is perfectly valid as OP is using javascript binding which allow javascript to call C# functions and vice versa and OP just needs a way to pass `System.Drawing.Color` in those function calls which is doable. Can you please vote to reopen the question so it can be answered?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'll vote to reopen it if OP edits their question to clarify which third party control they are using and also edits their question to include their current binding code.